# Create an object array without calling the constructors

Tags: c++, memory-alignment, c++03

for an embedded system we need a custom vector class, where the capacity is set during compile-time through a template parameter.

Until now we had an array of objects as a member variable.

```
template<class T, size_t SIZE>
class Vector {
     ...
     T data[SIZE];
}
```

The problem here of course is that if T isn't a POD, the default constructors of T are called. Is there any way to let data be uninitialized until a corresponding push() call (with placement new inside)? Just using

```
uint8_t data[SIZE * sizeof(T)];
```

possibly breaks the alignment of T. We absolutely cannot use dynamic memory, the total container size always needs to be known at compile-time. We also cannot use C++'s alignas specifier since the compiler does not support C++11 yet :(

Comment: out of curiosity: what do you mean with "breaks the alignment of T"? Isnt any aligment issue confined to whatever is inside the `sizeof(T)` bytes? I dont see how this would cause a problem

Comment: Not the best solution ever, but can't you simply create a default constructor which marks the object as "uninitialized", stored in a boolean or the like?

Comment: Looks like a use-case for placement new.

Comment: Note that you will still have to store the number of constructed elements to be able to call their destructors.

Comment: You can make data a pointer *data, and inside the vector constructor use operator new which does not call the constructor.

Comment: Currently we actually are initializing every element and mark it as valid/invalid, but now we'd like to do it "right". Placement new is a technique to call the constructor without allocating memory, we need to allocate memory without calling the constructor.

Comment: @tobi303 uint8_t can be aligned anyhow, we need it to be aligned as T.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin As I said, we absolutely cannot use any kind of dynamic memory. Otherwise we would have taken std::vector.

Comment: @Jgdo Destructors and dynamic memory are orthogonal.

Comment: Your data array will be on the stack and it needs to be at least default constructed.

Comment: Check out [`boost::container::static_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use placement `new` along with a union trick to get the alignment properly set.

```
// use `std::max_align_t` and `std::aligned_storage` when you have it
// since don't have access to alignof(), use the presumably max 
// alignment value
using MaxAlign = long; 

template <typename T, int size>
class UninitializedArray {

    union Node {
        char data[sizeof(T)];
        MaxAlign alignment;
    };

    Node aligned_data[size];
    bool initialized;

public:

    UninitializedArray() : initialized(false) {}
    void initialize() {
        for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(size); ++i) {
            new (&this->aligned_data[i].data) T();
        }
        this->initialized = true;
    }
    ~UninitializedArray() {
        if (this->initialized) {
            for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(size); ++i) {
                T* ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&this->aligned_data[i].data);
                ptr->~T();
            }
        }
    }

    T& operator[](int index) {
        if (!this->initialized) {
            this->initialize();
        }

        T* ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&this->aligned_data[i].data);
        return *ptr;
    }
};
```

And then use it like this

```
UninitializedArray<Something, 5> arr;
arr[0].do_something();
```

---

If you ever get C++17 working, then you can use `std::array` and `std::optional` to make this easy

```
std::optional<std::array<T, N>> optional_array;

// construct the optional, this will construct all your elements
optional_array.emplace();

// then use the value in the optional by "treating" the optional like
// a pointer
optional_array->at(0); // returns the 0th object
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would check if the compiler has support for alignment, ie gcc has `__attribute__(aligned(x))`, there is likely something similar.

Then if you absolutely have to have aligned uninitialized data without such support, you will have to waste some space

```
// Align must be power of 2
template<size_t Len, size_t Align>
class aligned_memory
{
public:
    aligned_memory()
      : data((void*)(((std::uintptr_t)mem + Align - 1) & -Align)) {}
    void* get() const {return data;}
private:
    char mem[Len + Align - 1];
    void* data;
};
```

And you'd use placement new with it

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Array
{
public:
    Array() : sz(0) {}
    void push_back(const T& t)
    {
        new ((T*)data.get() + sz++) T(t);
    }

private:
    aligned_memory<N * sizeof(T), /* alignment */> data;
    size_t sz;
};
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1efc5433ca2e61e)

The alignment of `T` can be found with C++11 `alignof`, check your compiler to see if it supports anything that can be used to find out its alignment. You can also just take a guess from printed pointer values and hope that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `std::vector<>` with a custom allocator that allocates on the stack.

This way you would create an empty vector, reserve the required space, which should be equal to the space your allocator allocates for you on the stack, and then populate the vector using `vector<>::emplace_back`. Your element type can be non-copyable but must be movable in this case.

E.g.:

```
#include <vector>

struct X {
    X(int, int);

    // Non-copyable.
    X(X const&) = delete;
    X& operator=(X const&) = delete;

    // But movable.
    X(X&&);
    X& operator=(X&&);
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct MyStackAllocator; // Implement me.

int main() {
    std::vector<X, MyStackAllocator<X, 10>> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    v.emplace_back(1, 2);
    v.emplace_back(3, 4);
}
```

Information about how to implement an allocator is widely available, for example, search YouTube for "c++ allocator".